# How to implement forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

Here, I'm creating a custom password reset page with custom form in Django. Also, I use `django-rest-resetpassword` package to generate reset tokens and send it via mail. Once the user clicks the link it verify the token for expiration, used-ones and if the tokens are good so the user can change the password.
say the url is `reset-password/verify-token/?token=123tq24uig32h` it redirects to `reset-password/verified/`

`reset-password/verified/` This page shows the template(i.e.,HTML page) for `new password` and `confirm password`.

When the tokens are good it is redirected to a template. So, There may arise a question that if the user already changed the password when he knows the url user can visit this page `reset-password/verified/` to prevent is I also passed token to `verified` page using get method and verify the status of the token. Now I need to validate the form-template of `new password` and `confirm password`

The code for token verificaiton is here

```
class CustomPasswordTokenVerificationView(APIView):
    """
      An Api View which provides a method to verifiy that a given pw-reset token is valid before actually confirming the
      reset.
    """
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = CustomTokenSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        toks = {"token" : request.GET["token"]}
        if (tokenVerificationFn(toks) == 0):
            return Response({'status': 'invalid'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check expiry date
        # expiry_date = reset_password_token.created_at + timedelta(hours=password_reset_token_validation_time)

        if (tokenVerificationFn(toks) == -1):
            # delete expired token
            # reset_password_token.delete()
            return Response({'status': 'expired'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check if user has password to change
        if(tokenVerificationFn(toks) == -2):
            return Response({'status': 'irrelevant'})

        if(tokenVerificationFn(toks) == 1):
            return redirect(("http://localhost:8000/account/password-reset/verified/?token={}").format(toks["token"]))
```

verified page code is here

```
class PasswordResetView(FormView):
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    template_name = "password-reset/passwordreset.html"

    success_url = "password-reset/resetsuccessfull.html"
    def get(self, request):
        token = {"token" : request.GET["token"]}
        verification = tokenVerificationFn(token)
        if (verification == 0):
            return Response({'status': 'invalid'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check expiry date
        # expiry_date = reset_password_token.created_at + timedelta(hours=password_reset_token_validation_time)

        if (verification == -1):
            # delete expired token
            # token.delete()
            return Response({'status': 'expired'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # check if user has password to change
        if(verification == -2):
            return Response({'status': 'irrelevant'})

        if(verification == 1):
            return render(request,"password-reset/passwordreset.html")
```

My forms.py this here

```
from django import forms

class PasswordResetForm(forms.Form):
    newPassword = forms.CharField(min_length=8)
    confirmPassword = forms.CharField(min_length=8)
```

I'm bit confused on how to implement the form validation and how to submit the form on successful validation. I need some help.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html

Comment: @michjnich In that link the request is check for POST but in PasswordResetView I'm working with GET request. How should I resolve this? Please help me sort this out

Comment: Don't work with GET for password stuff. It's not secure.